# Mobile Browser not recognizing click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to log an event object each time an element is clicked (doing this for debugging).

I am using this function:

```
$(window).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

This logs the click event on my desktop bowser; however, this doesn't log anything in the mobile consoles. Do mobile browsers not interpret click events as touch events?

Comment: Try using touchstart so $(window).on('click touchstart',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### That's because mobile browsers have ["touch" events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

You can capture both clicks and touches using:

```
$(window).on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```